# Resizing an element when the document resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'd like to resize an element when the document resizes.  If a draggable div is moved around and causes the document to scroll.  I want to resize an element like this `$("#page").css('height','120%');`.  I do that in the onresize event for a div.  Is that the right way?  Is there a different event that where I should do this?

Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="matting" onresize="resize_page();"> <!-- Begin page matting div --> 

  <div id="page"> <!-- Begin page div --> 

  </div> <!-- End page div --> 

</div> <!-- End page matting div --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function resize_page() { 
        alert ('resize_page'); 
        $("#page").css('height','120%'); 
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook into the draggable `stop` callback:

```
$("#matting" ).resizable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ...YOUR CODE... }
});
```

Comment: #matting is a regular div with a size in CSS specified as a percentage of the document window.  It is not explicitly defined as resizable.  Is this still the way to call my function?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook the resize event in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

A better solution would probably be to put a restriction on the draggable object so it can't move out of bound and scroll the page.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now,  the new code uses a [plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) that allows the resize method to be applied to every element.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9Ppb/
<< Resize the window.

Comment: The document resize because the scroll bars are added to the window.  The matting has an image that is stretched to fit the new size.  This seems to say that matting is resized.

Comment: I thought your suggestion might work.  But the alert doesn't show, saying that the resize isn't done.

Comment: The new code works if I manually resize the window.  What I am looking for is a way to do the #page resize when the document within the exiting window size is expanded. In order words I want to do this when the scrollbars automatically move because of new content.  This wasn't clear enough before.

Comment: This fiddle shows the scrolling when new content is added.  But the alert window showing that the element was resized doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reset the height of the page div to be that of the scrolling height of the parent div (the document).

```
     var page_height = $('#matting')[0].scrollHeight;
     $("#page").css('height',page_height);
```